# Is there a g_dbus function to update the non cached property value?

Tags: caching, properties, glib, gnome

I am working on a head unit project using a Raspberry Pi. The goal is to have a graphical user interface on the head unit that can control the phone when playing music.

I cant seem to get the phone to enable "Shuffle" or "Repeat".

I am using Bluez 5.45, and GLIB. I have basic control over play, stop, next.

Is there a similar function to g_dbus_proxy_set_cached_property()?

I have tried the function  g_dbus_proxy_set_cached_property() but it only updates the cached value, the phone never receives the value set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to set/get properties. I used the g_dbus_proxy_call_sync method.

```
g_dbus_proxy_call_sync (GDBusProxy *proxy,
                    const gchar *method_name,
                    GVariant *parameters,
                    GDBusCallFlags flags,
                    gint timeout_msec,
                    GCancellable *cancellable,
                    GError **error);
```

I needed to access the "org.freedesktop.DBUS.Properties" interface. I needed to use the "Set" method. It takes three paramaters.

`Set(String interface_name, String property_name, A value)`

1. interface_name - The interface the property is associated with
2. propertyName   - The name of the property
3. value          - The new value of the property (May be any valid DBUS type).

   `g_dbus_proxy_call_sync( myProxy,
                           "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Set",
                           g_variant_new ("(ssv)",
                           "org.bluez.MediaPlayer1",
                           "Repeat",
                           g_variant_new_string ("alltracks")),
                           G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE, // Flags
                            -1,                        // timeout
                             NULL,                 // cancellable
                            &error             // error
                            );`